# How to calculate the value of $f=\operatorname{dim}(X)-\operatorname{dim}(X \cap W)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $V$ is a complex vector space with $dim(V)=n$ and $W:dim(W)=n-1$ is the vector subspace of $V$. Suppose also that $X$ is a vector subspace of $V$ but $X\not\subset W$, that is, $X$ is not a subspace of $W$. Then, calculate the value of the equation $$f=\operatorname{dim}(X)-\operatorname{dim}(X \cap W)$$

What would be the solution of this problem? Any helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that as $X\not\subset W$, $X$ is not the zero subspace, and there exists at-least one $0\neq v\in X$ such that $v\not\in W$. Now given a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}\}$ of $W$, $\{v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1},v\}$ is necessarily a basis for $V$ (as these are $n$ linearly independent vectors in $V$). Moreover, this shows that $X+W\subset V\subset X+W=V$ and hence $\dim(X+W)=\dim(V)=n$. Now using the dimension theorem:
$$\dim(X)+\dim(W)=\dim(X+W)+\dim(X\cap W)\Rightarrow \dim(X)+n-1=n+\dim(X\cap W)$$ Which gives us:
$$\dim(X)-\dim(X\cap W)=1$$
Intuitively, $X$ can't have too many linearly independent vectors that are not in $W$, as that would make $X+W$ "too big".

Comment: Oh, a very well-explained answer. Thanks!